# Using IIS as a forward proxy between application and internet proxy server

Tags: iis, proxy

I have a problem inside the enterprise where we use a proxy server to access the internet. I want to enable internet access for application REST services. The application does not support proxy configuration. I want to use IIS as a forward proxy. The application will send the request to the IIS and IIS will forward the request to the correct internet endpoint using the internet proxy server.

I already configured the IIS website on port 8443 to forward all traffic to specific internet address (ARR). I also configured defaultProxy, which I understand should be the internet proxy server like:

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://proxyserver:port" scriptLocation="" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```

When I checked the log files on the internet proxy server, I don't find any traffic from IIS. It seems IIS does not forward the traffic to the internet using a defaultProxy settings.

What am I doing it wrong here?
Is there any other option to set up a forward proxy which could forward traffic to the internet using an internet proxy server?

Comment: IIS cannot be used as forward proxy in general (some Microsoft engineers might claim differently but you can test on your own). Use a real proxy product instead.

Comment: What would be the real proxy in this case? I tried to use SQUID but I had no success.

Comment: SQUID is a forward proxy and many use it with success. Tutorials/recommendations are off-topic here. Such is also not programming related.